# How can I display an image by an API URL? Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have an app in which it shows me data from an API. I made a service that gets the data, where URL(string = "") is the url of the API:

```
class Webservice {

    func getAllMatches(completion: @escaping ([Matches.Matchs]?) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "API")
            else {
                fatalError("URL is not correct!")
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            let matchs = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Matches.Matchs].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(matchs)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

Then I made a ViewModel in which the API fields were set:

```
class MatchListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var matches = [MatchViewModel]()


    init() {
        fetchMatch()


    }

    func fetchMatch() {

        Webservice().getAllMatches { matches in

            if let matches = matches {
                self.matches = matches.map(MatchViewModel.init)
            }
        }
    }

}


class MatchViewModel {

    let id = UUID()

    var match: Matches.Matchs

    init(match: (Matches.Matchs)) {
        self.match = match
    }


    var championship: String {
        return self.match.championship.name
    }

    var local_Name: String {
        return self.match.local.name
    }

    var local_Image: String  {
        return self.match.local.image
    }

    var local_goals: Double {
        return self.match.local_goals
    }

    var local_penalty_goals: Double {
        return self.match.local_penalty_goals
    }
    var stadium_Name: String {
        return self.match.stadium.name
    }

}
```

In the API, there is a field that shows an image, which is contained in a URL, I leave an example:

```
"local":{  
     "slug":"nombre",
     "name":"nombre",
     "short_name":"nombre",
     "image":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/funx-futbol/dashboard/ad.png"
 },
```

My question is: How can I display that image via that URL? The API query works, as it brings me the information I require, but I need to show me the image through that link, which I have not achieved.

Thanks for reading!

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc1Md.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loader like this to load the data:

```
import Combine

public class DataLoader: ObservableObject {

    public let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Data,Never>()

    public private(set) var data = Data() {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send(newValue)
        }
    }

    private let resourseURL: URL?

    public init(resourseURL: URL?){
        self.resourseURL = resourseURL
    }

    public func loadImage() {
        guard let url = resourseURL else {
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,_,_) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = data
            }
        }   .resume()
    }
}
```

And a struct like this to display it:

```
import SwiftUI 

struct WebImage: View {

    @ObservedObject private var imageLoader: DataLoader

    public init(imageURL: URL?) {
        imageLoader = DataLoader(resourseURL: imageURL)
    }

    public var body: some View {
        if let uiImage = UIImage(data: self.imageLoader.data) {
            return AnyView(Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit))
        } else {
            return AnyView(Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                            .onAppear(perform: { self.imageLoader.loadImage() }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank , but when I try to put "WebImage" in my view, I get an error in the forEach, the error says "Type '_' has no member 'id'". :/

Comment: Could you provide the code where you get an error please?

Comment: WebImage takes a URL? into its initialiser, so you have to declare it like this: WebImage(imageURL: URL(string: ""))

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize Data via init?(contentsOf:): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3126626-init and then you can use that data to initialize UIImage via init?(data:): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624106-init

If you would go this way remember that this Data initializer by default doesn't run on the background thread, so you can have bad performance, probably you would like to push it to background and then on completion use GCD to use result and update UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLImage](https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image) library if you do not want to write any custom classes. It has heaps of customization options you can apply to your remote image.

You can install it in your project by adding a swift package([steps](https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image#installation)).

I hope it helps.

Happy coding.