# Show Image in a List from an URL

Tags: swiftui

I've got a list that's being populated from a JSON API.

```
ForEach(booksVM.books.sorted { $0.popularidad > $1.popularidad}) { book in
    HStack {
        Image(URL: book.imagen)
        Text(book.nombre)
        Spacer()
    }
    Text(book.autor)
    Spacer()
}
```

3rd line is wrong but is what I'm trying to achieve.

Now, `book.imagen` is the Decodable variable for all the images urls of the JSON. How can I do this?

JSON just in case:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "The design of every day things",
    "autor": "Don Norman",
    "disponibilidad": true,
    "popularidad": 70,
    "imagen": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/410RTQezHYL._SX326_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "100 años de soledad",
    "autor": "Garcia Marquez",
    "disponibilidad": false,
    "popularidad": 43,
    "imagen": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51egIZUl88L._SX336_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
}
]
```

And Struct:

```
struct Book: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let nombre: String
    let autor: String
    let disponibilidad: Bool
    let popularidad: Int
    let imagen: String
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display an image by an API URL? Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878111/how-can-i-display-an-image-by-an-api-url-swift)

Comment: Kind of, is a loader the only way to do it? Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: You have to download the data - how else would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://dev.to/gualtierofr/remote-images-in-swiftui-49jp) I found one decision and modified it for you. The idea is to create **ImageView** with class **ImageLoader**:

```
struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader:ImageLoader
    @State var image:UIImage = UIImage()

    func imageFromData(_ data:Data) -> UIImage {
        UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
    }

    init(withURL url:String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString:url)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Image(uiImage: imageLoader.data != nil ? UIImage(data:imageLoader.data!)! : UIImage())
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width:100, height:100)
        }
    }

}

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataIsValid = false
    var data:Data?

    init(urlString:String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataIsValid = true
                self.data = data
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

and now you can use it for your list:

```
struct ListView: View {
    let urls = ["https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/410RTQezHYL._SX326_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg", "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51egIZUl88L._SX336_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(urls, id: \.self) { url in
                ImageView(withURL: url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the preview result:
[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! One quick question, in the List part, how can I add the functionality of the ForEach you have to the previous one I have, I tried just using `ImageView(withURL: book.imagen)` but doesn't work.

Comment: @luwec, it's hard to understand what mistake do you have? do you mean live preview or something else?

Comment: I already have a ForEach, your solution adds another ForEach which would create another list, I need to merge your ForEach with my ForEach.

Comment: @luwec, do you need something like this? 
```ForEach(books) { book in```
               ```VStack {```
                    ```HStack {```
                        ```ImageView(withURL: book.imagen)```
                        ```Text(book.nombre)```
                    ```}```
                    ```Text(book.autor)```
                    ```Spacer()```
                ```}```
           ```}```