# How Does One Display an Web-based Image in SwiftUI

Tags: image, download, swiftui

SwiftUI seems cool, but some things just seem hard to me. Even so, I would rather understand how best to do something the SwiftUI way rather than wrap pre-swiftui controllers and do something the old way. So let me start with a simple problem -- displaying a web image given a URL. There are solutions, but they are not all that easy to find and not all the easy to understand.

I have a solution and would like some feedback.  Below is an example of what I would like to do (the images is from Open Images).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imagePath: String = "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/440/19711210125_6c12414d8f_o.jpg"

    var body: some View {
        WebImage(imagePath: $imagePath).scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

My solution entails putting a little bit of code at the top of the body to start the image download. The image path has a @Binding property wrapper -- if it changes I want to update my view. There is also a myimage variable with a @State property wrapper -- when it gets set I also want to update my view. If everything goes well with the image load, myimage will be set and the an image displays.  The initial problem is that changing the state within the body will result in the view being invalidated and trigger yet another download, ad infinitum. The solution seems simple (the code is below). Just check imagePath and see if it has changed since the last time something was loaded. Note that in download I set prev immediately, which triggers another execution of body.  The conditional causes the state change to be ignored.

I read somewhere that @State checks for equality and will ignore sets if the value does not change. This kind of equality check will fail for UIImage. I expect three invocations of body: the initial invocation, the invocation when I set prev, and an invocation when I set image. I suppose I could add a mutable value for prev (i.e., a simple class) and avoid the second invocation.

Note that loading web content could have been accomplished using an extension and closures, but that's a different issue.  Doing so, would have shrunk WebImage to just a few lines of code.

So, is there a better way to accomplish this task?

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Learn
//
//  Created by John Morris on 11/26/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 John Morris. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct WebImage: View {
    @Binding var imagePath: String?
    @State var prev: String?
    @State var myimage: UIImage?
    @State var message: String?

    var body: some View {
        if imagePath != prev {
            self.downloadImage(from: imagePath)
        }
        return VStack {
            myimage.map({Image(uiImage: $0).resizable()})
            message.map({Text("\($0)")})
        }
    }

    init?(imagePath: Binding<String?>) {
        guard imagePath.wrappedValue != nil else {
            return nil
        }

        self._imagePath = imagePath
        guard let _ = URL(string: self.imagePath!) else {
            return nil
        }

    }

    func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
    }

    func downloadImage(from imagePath: String?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.prev = imagePath
        }

        guard let imagePath = imagePath, let url = URL(string: imagePath) else {
            self.message = "Image path is not URL"
            return
        }

        getData(from: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                self.message = error.localizedDescription
                return
            }

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                self.message = "No Response"
                return
            }

            guard (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 404 {
                    self.message = "Page, \(url.absoluteURL), not found"
                } else {
                    self.message = "HTTP Status Code \(httpResponse.statusCode)"
                }
                return
            }

            guard let mimeType = httpResponse.mimeType else {
                self.message = "No mimetype"
                return
            }

            guard mimeType == "image/jpeg" else {
                self.message = "Wrong mimetype"
                return
            }

            print(response.debugDescription)
            guard let data = data else {
                self.message = "No Data"
                return
            }

            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    self.myimage = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var images = ["https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2260/5744476392_5d025d6a6a_o.jpg",
                  "https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8521/8685165984_e0fcc1dc07_o.jpg",
                  "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/204/507064030_0d0cbc850c_o.jpg",
                  "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/440/19711210125_6c12414d8f_o.jpg"
    ]
    @State var imageURL: String?
    @State var count = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            WebImage(imagePath: $imageURL).scaledToFit()
            Button(action: {
                self.imageURL = self.images[self.count]
                self.count += 1
                if self.count >= self.images.count {
                    self.count = 0
                }
            }) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display an image by an API URL? Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878111/how-can-i-display-an-image-by-an-api-url-swift)

Comment: This addresses the mechanics of loading an image, but what I was looking for is something as simple as -- Image("myimage"). In my case, something like WebImage("myURL").  I think I have something that works and is consistent with the declarative style of SwiftUI without adding a lot of complexity underneath the covers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things.  First, you generally want to allow a placeholder View for when the image is downloading.  Second, you should cache the image otherwise if you have something like a tableView where it scrolls off screen and back on screen, you are going to keep downloading the image over an over again.  Here is an example from one of my apps of how I addressed it:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import UIKit

class ImageCache {
  enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case dataConversionFailed
    case sessionError(Swift.Error)
  }
  static let shared = ImageCache()
  private let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()
  private init() { }
  static func image(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, ImageCache.Error> {
    guard let image = shared.cache.object(forKey: url as NSURL) else {
      return URLSession
        .shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap { (tuple) -> UIImage in
          let (data, _) = tuple
          guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw Error.dataConversionFailed
          }
          shared.cache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSURL)
          return image
        }
        .mapError({ error in Error.sessionError(error) })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return Just(image)
      .mapError({ _ in fatalError() })
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

class ImageModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var image: UIImage? = nil
  var cacheSubscription: AnyCancellable?
  init(url: URL) {
    cacheSubscription = ImageCache
      .image(for: url)
      .replaceError(with: nil)
      .receive(on: RunLoop.main, options: .none)
      .assign(to: \.image, on: self)
  }
}

struct RemoteImage : View {
  @ObservedObject var imageModel: ImageModel
  init(url: URL) {
    imageModel = ImageModel(url: url)
  }
  var body: some View {
    imageModel
      .image
      .map { Image(uiImage:$0).resizable() }
      ?? Image(systemName: "questionmark").resizable()
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this work? (How should I use it?)